# # variables in URL address in js

Tags: javascript, url, variables

How can i retrieve variables from the URL address?
am using this code but it is not working:

```
var x=window.location;
        var y = x.indexOf('#', 0);
        x=x.substring(y,x.length);
```

am receiving the following error:

```
Error: x.indexOf is not a function
```

Comment: More information about `location`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not window.location but window.location.href

Still, I would use window.location.hash

Answer (score 3):

You get the error because `window.location` is an object, not a string. Try `window.location.hash` to obtain the part after the `#`.

Comment: I think window.location.hash contains the # character.